# Difference between installing pandas with python and python3

Tags: python, pandas, installation, module

I have to install pandas but nothing I am trying seems to be working. I have tried to run this in cmd

```
pip install wheel
pip install pandas
pip3 install pandas
python -m pip install pandas
python3 -m pip install pandas
```

And even updated setuptools. When I run `python -m pip install pandas`, it tells me that the requirements are satisfied

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (1.1.3)
```

But when I change it up to `python3 -m pip install pandas`, I get this outrageously long error with the heading, `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`

So I have 2 questions. 1, what was the difference between me using `python` and `python3`. 2, is there a more reliable way I can install pandas?

These are some of the error messages when I run the installation

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a85382ti\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
       cwd: None
```

And then it tells me I have all these modules missing but I don't know how to install them

```
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
```

Comment: Please use `python 3.7` you might not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are on Linux or Mac, `python` stands for **Python Version 2** and `python3` of course stands for **Python Version 3**. You should not use python 2 because it is no longer being actively developed and it's support has also been dropped more than a year ago. So long story short use python 3.

For your second question just run `pip3 install pandas` in your terminal and you are good to go.

Comment: I am getting the same error message and I am using command prompt on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

`python` is the old version that is Python 2 and currently the `python 3` is under existence.

We can say python 2 has now become obselete

Most of the libraries might get error while using python2 or python3. Meaning there might me some incompatible libraries that might support python2 or vice versa.

In Python 3, text strings are Unicode by default. In Python 2, strings are stored as ASCII by default–you have to add a “u” if you want to store strings as Unicode in Python 2.x.

Also the print statement is now replaced with a print function.

Coming to your question, what you can do is remove python 2 from your system and run `pip3 install pandas`

Also if you are facing difficulties further you can try working with some virtual environment [like this](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment).

Comment: If I cannot get pandas to install with python, is the virtual environment my last go-to? As in my last option?

Comment: No what can you do is if you dont want `python2` in your system, remove it and then work only with `python3` .further just keep using `python3` and `pip3` .Virtual environment is just to keep project dependencies separate from each other.

Comment: `pip3 install pandas` is giving me the same error as `pip install pandas`

Comment: could you check the python version on your system.?  Also please list the error message in your question. Please remove python2 from your system if its not required

Comment: My python version is python3.9.0. The error message is really really long. Would you still want to see it?

Comment: In windows generally we do not use `pip3 install pandas`, we use `pip install pandas`, Please paste atleast 2-5 lines of the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223395/discussion-between-prxvidxnce-and-dqureshiumar).